# Take picture and set it to UIImageView in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiimageview, camera

Is there a way to take a picture on the iPad without going through the Apple controls ? I have seen a bunch of apps that do this,

For example, when you add a new contact in iPhone, on the top left side it shows `add photo` when we click on that, camera opens up and it takes pic and saves to `add photo`..

I want to implement same functionality.. is it possible on iPad ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need to do is , Add a button first, with the title "Add Photo" or with custom image.

Then on the click of the button add the following code :

```
    if (([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:
              UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera] == NO)
            return NO;

        UIImagePickerController *cameraUI = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        cameraUI.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
[self presentViewController: cameraUI animated: YES completion:nil];
```

It will open up the camera, then you click the image and then tap "use" and You have to implement the UIImagePickerControllerDelegate method **imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:** and then store the UIImage to wherever you want, with whatever file name you want, using NSFileManager methods.

Comment: Good ans it is working but, camera takes image bit after that it doesnot load my image which i have taken into `imageview` here is my code `- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    
    UIImage *image =  [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    
    [imgVw setImage:image];
    
    imgVw.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
}`

Comment: There might be some other problem I think, Because this code works completely fine at my end and it shows the image in the imageView also

Answer (score 1):

Using image picker controller you can use the same functionality as you described in your question.

For that you need to convert the picture into image data & display it in uiimageview

You can refer this : [UIImageView Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImageView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

This will provide you examples too.

This answer of [Taking a picture from the camera and show it in a UIImageView](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7820983/1538079) will provide you proper answer..

Enjoy Programming!!